# Scaffolding and Mixins with Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap docs says about scaffolding and mixins, I couldn't understand those correctly - what they meant by scaffolding. I googled about scaffolding in css but I didn't get a good idea from any links. Also I could find some pages about mixins the are saying all differently such as mixins is class with combinations of methods from other classes, mixins are frame work and etc. But didn't get a complete idea about what is mixin, is it a concept or framework. Can any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

Mixins basically acts as vaiables in CSS Preprocessors, like LESS. if you write mixin you can use it n number of time anywhere in you dynamic stylesheet.

Consider this example:

```
.RoundBorders {
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

#menu {
  color: gray;
  .RoundBorders;
}
```

If we write this in our Dynamic stylesheet it will result in:

```
#menu {
  color: gray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
```

you can use .RoundBorders mixin in you Class or id anywhere. It makes you task simple, you need not to write those property again if you mention this mixin.